# what is type of this Response type ? (it's no json, or xml)

Tags: xml, json, rest, httpwebresponse

I am familiar with json or xml response format/type.

JSON :

```
{
    "status": "success"
    "code": "10"

}
```

XML :

```
<status> 
     success 
</status>

<code> 
     10 
</code>
```

But i received this instead :

```
status=success&code=10
```

What is the name of above format ? and what type of response is that? is it *text/html* ?

Comment: Looks like URL parameters.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Who says it's _any_ standard format?

Comment: Fiddler can help! its text/html

Comment: Just split is using String library split function... and you are good to go to get the values.

Comment: I only want to know what kind of format that.

Comment: It's something invented by the author of that particular piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a query string handled badly by the client... Just check the client post form or check the requests for parameters from query string and translate them to use.

The encoding is handled usually as urlencoded, I really don't know what encoding is the default, but the rcf of HTTP 1.0 should say

python urlparse handle that as ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded***

If it will not be possible to change the client side, try to translate as urlencoded always.. it was not the right way , but it's better then nothing.